# Shopware Commercial - installing Advanced Search plugin

Tags: shopware6

in my local dev environment (devenv) I try to install the advanced search plugin for Shopware.
Shopware version is the latest (6.5.5.1), composer does not allow me to require version 3.4.2, as it's compatible only with Shopware 6.4.20.2 maximum.
Somewhere I read that there should be a feature flag to activate in order to use the plugin with Shopware 6.5.x
Anyone has information on this matter?
Shopware commercial is installed and active.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Zirc75 the latest version of the commercial plugin is 5.5.0 and is compatible with Shopware 6.5.5.0 and 6.5.5.1

Comment: Commercial plugin is in place (v5.5.0) and activated, if I require 'store.shopware.com/swagenterprisesearchplatform' I'm locked to version 3.1.0
I suppose I need to require a different package, but can't find any documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the advanced search you installed is the old advanced search. It works for the old version of Shopware 6.4 ( incompatible with Shopware 6.5 ). We have developed a new version of advanced search in the commercial plugin, compatible with Shopware 6.5. You can read a document here

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/products/extensions/advanced-search/

Comment: I installed and activated the commercial plugin, but I don't see any documentation on how to use the commercial plugin to install advanced-search.

By the way this leads to a 404 page https://developer.shopware.com/docs/products/extensions/search/

Comment: Your link is miss advance text  :)
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/products/extensions/advanced-search/

It's had an override in the search setting component. You can go to 
Settings -> Search to check
.